# Conditionally include file in an RPM

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

How can I conditionally include a file in an `.rpm` based on a define `_foobar` being set or not? The define `_foobar` would contain the absolute path inside the build root. The file is there.

According to the documentation, I expected the following to work (note: there are more files in this `%files` section, but this is the gist):

```
%files
%if %{_foobar}
%{_foobar}
%endif
```

which, however, gives me the error:

```
error: parse error in expression
error: /path/to/specfile:LINENO: parseExpressionBoolean returns -1
```

where `/path/to/specfile:LINENO` is the path to the `.spec` file and the line number of the line with the `%if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem

step 1 :

```
   In Build section .. somewhere I wrote :
 %build
  .....
  #check my condition here & if true define some macro
  %define is_valid %( if [ -f /usr/bin/myfile ]; then echo "1" ; else echo "0"; fi )
 #after his normal continuation
 .....
 ...
```

Step 2: in install section

```
  %install
  ......
  #do something in that condition
  if %is_valid
  install -m 0644 <file>
  %endif
  #rest all your stuff
  ................
```

Step 3:in files section

```
   %files
   if %is_valid 
   %{_dir}/<file>
   %endif
```

That's it

It works.

PS : I cannot give you full code hence giving all useful snippet

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to [this blog post](http://backreference.org/2011/09/17/some-tips-on-rpm-conditional-macros/) I found a version that works for me:

```
%files
%if %{?_foobar:1}%{!?_foobar:0}
%{_foobar}
%endif
```

What this does is to expand to `%if 1` if the define is set and `%if 0` otherwise.

If someone else has a better solution, please answer. I'll certainly prefer accepting someone else's answer over my own.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. This really works. Although there are some nice things here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701771/if-condition-inside-the-files-section-on-a-spec-file , but that didn't solve my problem