# How to create a conditional package using RPM packaging

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am using a spec file to create an RPM package. I want to package only those files which are present on my system. In my `%files` section, I am writing the files which I want to include in my package. The conditional and non conditional packages are included in the following manner.

```
%files
    %if "%is_file1_present"
    %attr (-, root, root) /location/to/file1
    %attr (-, root, root) /location/to/file2
%endif
%attr (-, root, root) /location/to/file3
%attr (-, root, root) /location/to/file4
```

`%is_file1_present` is defined in the `%build` section like this.

```
%build
%define is_file1_present %( if [ -f /location/to/file1 ]; then echo "1" ; else echo "0"; fi )`
```

While trying to build RPM package, it seems to ignore the if condition. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There are a few possible ways to do this.  See [If condition inside the %Files section on a SPEC file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18701771/4154375) and [Conditionally include file in an RPM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18775680/4154375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a easier solution:

In your install section; only copy the files that are present; and use wildcards in the files section:

```
%install
install -d -m 0755 "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/location/to"
cp file* ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/location/to/

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/location/to/file*
```

**NOTE**: this works, but that means that your spec file will not always create the same package, which isn't very nice...

Comment: I tried this method and it says "File not found by glob". I was just wondering why doesn't if else statement work in %files section

Comment: try with the edits to my answer. You can debug a little; this is supposed to work; I use it very often. You can read the output of the rpmbuild command to see what goes wrong.

Comment: After making a few adjustments, your solution worked. Thanks !!